# Why are my hair particles being pulled to the origin?

Tags: materials, particles, cache

After baking and adding a material to the mesh, the hair stretches and gets pulled to the origin point. If I delete the bake and remove the particle system from view by hitting the little monitor button and then bring it back by hitting it again, it goes back to normal. How do I fix this so that I can add materials? I've tried turning the use modifier stack button on and off.

Imgur Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0bJk.jpg
Blend File: https://blend-exchange.com/b/kYdR07ka

Comment: I did exactly what you did in the video and it works completely fine to me... https://imgur.com/a/s68O1TZ

Comment: Weird... I guess I'll start over

Comment: @MikoCG can you tell me what version of Blender you're using? I think this might be a bug
https://developer.blender.org/T91887

Comment: I am using 3.0.0. right now, maybe it was a bug, if it was non replicable on my system it may have been related to combination of your system and blender